# Can I run a specific Firefox version using HtmlUnitDriver()?

Tags: htmlunit

I am struggling from few days on Headless browser. The aim is to run the selenium test cases on Linux VM which has only the command line and no GUI.
My Test Suite runs with only Firefox 35 version. And this only firefox is installed on the Linux machine.

What I am doing is:
1) Run Xvfb server on a port
2) set DISPLAY to that port
3) Run my code.

In my code, I am instantiating the htmlUnit driver as:

```
else if (env == Environment.HEADLESS_LINUX) {
capability.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capability.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
capability.setBrowserName(BrowserType.FIREFOX);
capability = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnit();
HtmlUnitDriver unitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capability);
logger.debug("driver is set to Headless browser");
```

}

PROBLEM: The code is unable to locate the Xpaths whereas when I run it on a machine with GUI with Firefox browser. All web elements gets located and cases get passed.
Is the HtmlUnit running Firefox_35 in background? Is there any solution?
Please help...

Comment: HtmlUnit is a headless browser. It doesn't have anything to do with Firefox. So, just like Chrome and IE are not running Firefox in the background, HtmlUnit isn't either.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Ok Roget that but then "capability = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnit(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17 or FIREFOX_24)" What is this for?

Comment: What does the javadoc say? The current version (https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html) doesn't havce any such method. But I guess it uses HtmlUnit and tells it to pretend it's Firefox 17 (i.e. send the corresponding user-agent string as header rather than the HtmlUnit user-agent).

Comment: Thank you for making things clear. I am now fixing the locators for headless. :)